# Modifying sparce matrix using fancy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use fancy indexing to modifying a large sparce matrix. Suppose you have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
b = sp.lil_matrix(a)
c = sp.lil_matrix((3,4))
c[[1,2], 0] = b[[1,2], 0]
```

However, this code gives the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch in assignment
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Both matrices have the same shape and this usually works if both matrices are numpy arrays. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I **don't see** the error with python 3.5.3, numpy 1.12.1, scipy 0.18.1, however, I **see** it with numpy 1.18.5,  scipy 1.4.1. The current versions of numpy and scipy are 1.20.3 and 1.6.3.

Comment: ... and they don't work :(

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using python 3.8.6 and the current versions of numpy and scipy (1.20.3 and 1.6.3). I get the error with these versions. Do you know what could be the issue ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: This may require studying the sparse code.  Sparse matrices are not a subclass of `ndarray`, so indexing does not necessarily work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is a bug with the sparse `__setitem__`. I've run into it before (but I just worked around it). Now I actually looked into it; first, you can fix this pretty easily:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
b = sp.lil_matrix(a)
c = sp.lil_matrix((3,4))
c[[1,2], 0] = b[[1,2], 0]
```

This raises the `ValueError` you saw. This doesn't and works as expected:

```
c[[1,2], 0] = b[[1,2], [0]]

>>> c.A
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0., 0.],
       [9., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Lets just walk through [the offending `__setitem__`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/_index.py#L75) (I'm going to omit a lot of code that doesn't get called):

```
row, col = self._validate_indices(key)
```

This is fine - `row = [1, 2]` and `col = 0`

```
col = np.atleast_1d(col)
i, j = _broadcast_arrays(row, col)
```

So far so good - `i = [1, 2]` and `j = [0, 0]`

```
if i.ndim == 1:
# Inner indexing, so treat them like row vectors.
    i = i[None]
    j = j[None]

broadcast_row = x.shape[0] == 1 and i.shape[0] != 1
broadcast_col = x.shape[1] == 1 and i.shape[1] != 1
```

Here's our problem - `i` and `j` both got turned into row vectors with shape `(1, 2)`. `x` here is what you're trying to assign (`b[[1,2], 0]`), which is of shape `(2, 1)`; the next step raises a `ValueError` cause `x` and the indices don't align.

```
>>> c[[1,2], 0] = b[[1,2], 0].A

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (2,)
```

Here's the same problem but `__setitem__` broadcasts `x` into a `(2,2)` array, which then fails again because it's larger than the array you're assigning it to.

The workaround (`b[[1,2], [0]]`) has a shape of `(1, 2)` which is not correct, but that error ends up cancelling out the error in indexing `c`.

I'm not sure exactly what the logic is behind this indexing code so I'm not sure how to fix this without introducing other subtle bugs.